# Proving $\forall f\in \mathscr F\exists g\in \mathscr F $ so that $g(f(1)) = 2$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, proof-writing

Let $\mathscr F$ denote the set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.
Prove or disprove.

(a) $\forall f\in \mathscr F\exists g\in \mathscr F $ so that $g(f(1)) = 2$.

(b) $\forall f\in \mathscr F\exists g\in \mathscr F $ so that $f(g(1)) = 2$.

(c) Let $f\in \mathscr F$ be define by: $f(1)=2,f(2)=3,f(3)=2$. Find the number of functions $g\in \mathscr F $so that $f(g(f(1))) = 2$.

Comment: (a) What about setting $g$ equal to a well-chosen constant function, for instance? (b) Is $2$ in the image of every function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ is true. Just take $g:x\mapsto 2$.

$(b)$ is false. If you take $f:x\mapsto 1$, no matter what $g$ is, the image of an element by $f\circ g$ will be $1$.

$(c)$ $f(g(f(1)))=2$

$f(g(2))=2$

Since we want $f(g(2))=2$, we have $g(2)=1$ or $g(2)=3$. Then for $g(1)$ and $g(3)$, we can chose any one of the three numbers so you get $2 \times 3 \times 3 = 18$ functions.